# CASE WHEN THEN yielding a value including an apostrophe

Tags: case, data-cleaning, apostrophe, geography

I'm cleaning geographic data from France, trying to get the department of each observation. For some observations, I have rather the city name and I want it to be its department.

E.g., Dijon should be Côte-d'Or.

So, when I write

```
CASE WHEN country = 'France' AND region = 'Dijon' THEN 'Côte-d'Or'
```

I am writing three apostrophes and it cannot be executed.

How can I solve it without losing the apostrophe?

Answer (score 0):

By putting another apostrohe before it, the output is the correct one.